# Error in Julia: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching isless(::Vector{Int64}, ::Int64)

Tags: function, julia, nosuchmethoderror

I am writing a code in julia but I am getting this error: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching isless(::Vector{Int64}, ::Int64). The part of mu code is:

```
X = []
function form(;a, b, c, d,e)
if a == 1 && b == 0
        @assert c <= 1000 "error."
    else
        @error failed"
end
.....
push!(x, form(a=2, b=5, c=[0,0], d=[0,1], e=[0,0]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you that there is no method for checking if a vector is less than an integer. You can write `.<=` to [broadcast](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#Broadcasting) the less-than comparison, which will perform the comparison element by element, but then you will want `any` or `all` or some other logic to transform that comparison output into a single true/false.

```
julia> [0, 0] <= 1000
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching isless(::Vector{Int64}, ::Int64)
Closest candidates are:
  isless(::AbstractVector, ::AbstractVector) at abstractarray.jl:2612
  isless(::AbstractFloat, ::Real) at operators.jl:186
  isless(::Real, ::Real) at operators.jl:434
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] <(x::Vector{Int64}, y::Int64)
   @ Base .\operators.jl:356
 [2] <=(x::Vector{Int64}, y::Int64)
   @ Base .\operators.jl:405
 [3] top-level scope
   @ REPL[1]:1

julia> [0, 0] .<= 1000
2-element BitVector:
 1
 1

julia> any([0, 1003] .<= 1000)
true

julia> all([0, 0] .<= 1000)
true
```

Comment: thank you. you mean instead of @assert, I should try with all or any? will that effect the result?

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately, I am getting this error:   MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Vector{Int64} to an object of type Int64

Comment: The error from your code is coming from `c <= 1000` (regardless of the @assert). Julia does not know how you want to compare a vector `c` and check if it is less than an integer `1000`. You need to be more specific about how you want this check to be performed, and what you decide will affect the result. Alternatively, you can call `form` with only integer arguments like `form(a=2, b=5, c=0, d=1, e=0)`. Then it is clear to Julia how to compare two integers. The commented error is again telling you what is wrong; you passed Julia a vector somewhere it expected a scalar integer.